# Python file read() and readline() counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

It looks like python keeps track of each run of read() and readline(). It is incremental, by each run, and in the end, it does not return any value. How to find this counter, and read a specific line at any time?

EDIT: My goal is to read a large file of a few Gb in size, hundreds of thousands of lines. If this an iterator then it is insufficient, I do not want to load the whole file in the memory. How do I jump to a specific line without having to read unnecessary lines?

A text file with just 3 lines.

```
# cat sample.txt
This is a sample text file. This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3

# python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file = open('sample.txt', 'r')
>>> file.readline()
'This is a sample text file. This is line 1\n'
>>> file.readline()
'This is line 2\n'
>>> file.readline()
'This is line 3\n'
>>> file.readline()
''
>>> file.readline()
''
>>> file.read()
''
>>> file.read(0)
''
>>> file.read()
''
>>>

# python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file = open('sample.txt', 'r')
>>> file.read()
'This is a sample text file. This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3\n'
>>> file.read()
''
>>> file.readline()
''
>>>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want. You can combine `readline` with `enumerate` to get tupels of line number and actual line.

Comment: @tobias_k I want to read any line in any order. Here is I use `readline()` it increments, goes to the next line, and stops giving value at the end. Where do I specify the line number to be read? and why can't I user `read()` after I used it once?

Comment: `file.tell()` returns the current offset into the file. It does *not* tell you want line you are on, as the file itself is not really a collection of lines, but a collection of bytes. The `readline` method simply reads until it finds the next newline character; the file itself doesn't care about lines.

Comment: If you treat the file as an iterator, you can use `enumerate(file)` to create an iterator that yields line-number/line pairs rather than just lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file object in Python is an iterator, iterating over the different lines in the file. You can use `readlines()` to read all the (remaining) lines at once into a list, or `read()` to read a single or all (remaining) characters in the file (default is all, use a parameter for the number of chars to read), but the default behaviour (if you iterate the file directly) is the same as with `readline`, i.e. yielding the next line from the file.

You can combine that with `enumerate` to get another iterator yielding the line number along with each line (the first line having number `0` unless you specify `enumerate`'s `start` parameter), or to get a specific line:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> lines = enumerate(f)
>>> next(lines)
(0, 'first line\n')
>>> next(lines)
(1, 'second line\n')
>>> next(lines)
(2, 'third line\n')

>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> lines = enumerate(f)
>>> next(l for i, l in lines if i == 3)
'fourth line\n'
```

There's also the `seek` method, which can be used to jump to a specific character in the file, which is useful for "resetting" the file to the first position (alternatively to re-opening it), but does not help much in finding a specific line unless you know the exact length of each line. (see below)

If you want to "read any line in any order" the simplest way is to actually read *all* the lines into a list using `readlines` and then accessing items in that list (provided that your file is not too large).

```
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> lines[3]
'fourth line\n'
>>> lines[1]
'second line\n'
```

---

> My goal is to read a large file of a few Gb in size, hundreds of thousands of lines.

Since the only way for Python to know where a line ends, and thus where a particular line starts, is to count the number of `\n` characters it encounters, there's no way around reading the entire file. If the file is very large, and you have to repeatedly read lines out of order, it might make sense to read the file *once* one line at a time, storing the starting positions of each line in a dictionary. Afterwards, you can use `seek` to quickly jump to and then read a particular line.

```
f = open("test.txt")
total = 1
lines = {}
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    lines[i] = total - 1
    total += len(line)
# jump to and read individual lines
f.seek(lines[3])
print(f.readline())
f.seek(lines[0])
print(f.readline())
```

Comment: Worth noting: since the iterator does its own buffering, do not mix use of `next` and `read`/`readline` with the same file object.

Comment: My goal is to read a large file of a few Gb in size, hundreds of thousands of lines.  If this an iterator then it is insufficient, I do not want to load the whole file in the memory. How do I jump to a specific line without having to read unnecessary lines?

Comment: @KapishM I don't think that you can. After all, the only way Python can "know" which line it currently is on is by counting `\n` characters. See my comment about `seek`. Reading the lines until you find your line seems like the best bet. If you have to do this repeatedly, you might create a dictionary mapping line numbers to positions in the file so you can use `seek` when revisiting a line.

Comment: @tobias_k This can work for me. I can go back and forth read any line. Thanks...

Comment: @tobias_k Will `open` still load the whole file in the memory, will it load the whole file in the memory to `enumerate`?

Comment: @KapishM No, `open` only initializes the file handle; only when you do `read()` with no parameters or `readlines()` (plural) it will read the entire file. (Given your file is so large, I think you'd notice...)

Answer (score 1):

The file object (i.e. from `open(file)`) behaves as an iterator when `readline()` is used. There is no counter, per se. This can be observed if you run `file.__next__()` in place of `file.readline()`.

The simple solution if you don't mind reading the whole file at once is just to create a list of all the lines and then reference the ones you're interested in, as

```
lines=file.readlines() # this is a list
```

Comment: Thank you. I see `file.readlines()` is giving me an array of all lines.